# printing documents is slow on 64 bit windows machine when compared with 32 bit windows machine

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I have developed a Windows Service using C# which prints the documents from my C# windows application.
The service prints the documents fast when my printer is connected to windows 32 bit machine(windows 2003 OS) but the printing slows down when the printer is connected to windows 64 bit machine(windows 2008 OS).i.e the number of pages printed per minute is less on win 2008 when compared to win 2003

```
         protected PrintDocument _PrintDocument;
         public  PrintPreviewDialog _PrintPreviewDlg;

        _PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = LandScapePrint;
        _PrintPreviewDlg.Height = ReportPreviewHeight;
        _PrintPreviewDlg.Width = ReportPreviewWidth;
        _PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = PrintDocumentMargin_Top;
        _PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = PrintDocumentMargin_Bottom;
        _PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = PrintDocumentMargin_Left;
        _PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = PrintDocumentMargin_Right;
        _PrintPreviewDlg.Document = _PrintDocument;
        _PrintPreviewDlg.Document.Print();
```

Can some one please help me out to make my documents printing speed same on both Operating systems,

Thanks & Regards
Chaithanya

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the printer driver in Windows 2008 machine is causing the printing to be slow by trying do some optimization. Compare the printer settings in both the machines.

1. Keep the printer settings same in both Windows 2003 and Windows 2008. If it works enforce these settings in your code.
2. If the above didn't work, you could downgrade your driver with that available in windows 2003 (not recommended). Sometimes this wouldn't work also. Give it a try.